# Saxon descending order

Tags: xml, sorting, saxon

To get elements in ascending order with saxon we write this...

```
saxon:sort(sale, saxon:expression('@price * @qty'))
```

How to get the elements in descending order?

Thank you in advance.

Décio Maigret Macamo.

Answer (score 0):

Why not

```
saxon:sort(sale, -saxon:expression('@price * @qty'))
```

Or perhaps

```
reverse(saxon:sort(sale, saxon:expression('@price * @qty')))
```

Or for more flexibility you might try moving from XPath to XQuery (depending on your environment and constraints).